# Use a specific database with a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can I specify the database to use when a `ModelForm` saves its data?

The [multiple-database support in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/) means that I can define more databases than just the `default`. For example:

```python
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    },
    },
    'staging': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': 'db.example.com',
        # …
    },
}
```

This allows a model manager to query a different database from the default:

```python
from django import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    # …

queryset = Foo.objects.using('staging').all()
```

A `ModelForm` subclass also interacts with the database:

```python
from django import forms

from .models import Foo

class FooImportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = [
            # …
        ]

fields = {
    # …
}
form = FooImportForm(fields)
form.save()
```

How can I specify that the `FooModelForm` instance should use the `staging` database when I `form.save()`? I can't see a place where to specify the equivalent of `using('staging')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Model.save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) accepts the `using` parameter to specify the database:

```python
foo = Foo(fields)
foo.save(using='staging')
```

The [`ModelForm.save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) returns the `Model` instance:

```
foo_form = FooImportForm(fields)
foo = foo_form.save()
```

The `ModelForm.save` method can optionally be told not to commit:

```
foo_form.save(commit=False)
```

Putting it all together:

```
foo_form = FooImportForm(fields)
foo = foo_form.save(commit=False)
foo.save(using='staging')
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever form do not commit first then now you get the model object and save it `using`

```
f = form.save(commit=False)
f.save(using='staging')
```