# Specify the database for a Django ModelForm instance

Tags: django, database-connection

How can I **specify which database** (by its alias name) a Django ModelForm should use?

A [Django ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/) knows its corresponding model, and the fields included.

The `ModelForm` instance clearly *knows* how to specify a database, internally. It can validate its fields against the database, and can save a new model instance to the database. This implies its operations have knowledge of which database to use.

I can't find how to specify any database other than the default, when creating the `ModelForm` nor when it interacts with the database::

```python
import csv

from cumquat_app.forms import CumquatImportForm

db_alias = 'foo'

reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
for row in reader:
    fields = make_fields_from_input_row(reader)

    # Wanted: ‘form = CumquatInputForm(fields, using=db_alias)’.
    form = CumquatImportForm(fields)

    # Wanted: ‘if form.is_valid(using=db_alias)’.
    if form.is_valid():

        # Wanted: ‘form.save(using=db_alias)’.
        form.save()
```

What I need is to specify the database alias as an external user of the `ModelForm`, when *creating* the instance or when *calling* `ModelForm.clean` or `ModelForm.is_valid` or `ModelForm.save` etc.

The same way I can with the ‘using’ hook of [`QuerySet.using('foo')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset),
or [`Model.save(using='foo')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save).

- Note that this is *not* a job for multi-database routing policy configuration. The use case is that I need to specify exactly one database, only known at run time. If the connection fails it should not fall back to any other, so database routes are the wrong hammer for this nail.
- I can [request the `ModelForm.save` method to not commit its change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37741546/70157) (with `commit=False`) and then use the `Model.save` directly. That does not address the other behaviour of a `ModelForm` which accesses the database, so it is not a solution to this question.
- A [`ModelManager.db_manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases) could do the job, if I use it to create the model instance. But I'm relying on the form to create the instance; I can't create a model instance because I don't have field values to assign yet. That's the job of the form.
- If it matters: this is in a management command, where I need to be able
  to specify from the command line that a particular database alias is the
  context for a command.

What is the **equivalent for `using='foo'`** when instantiating a `ModelForm` for the model, or calling its methods (`ModelForm.clean`, `ModelForm.save`, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone can find a way to do it as requested using the `ModelForm` interface, I can only conclude **Django offers no way to do this** with the `ModelForm` API as it stands.